# " symbol usage in user snippets of Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm learning C programming language and as you know there is a command `printf` and it uses the "" symbol. I'm using Visual Studio Code for writing C. And I want add a snippet for printf. But when I tried adding these letters in JSON file of snippets and using these snippets,

```
"printf": {
        "prefix":"printf",
        "body": ["printf("$1"$2);"]
    }
```

it turns into this:

```
    printf(
);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think double quote characters inside JSON string literals need to be escaped with a backslash character, i.e. replace `"` with `\"` inside the string.

Comment: See http://json.org/ – it covers the JSON specification simply.  It isn't a complex specification anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the backslash character `\` to escape the `"` quotes inside your snippet content string.

```
"printf": {
    "prefix":"printf",
    "body": ["printf(\"$1\"$2);"]
}
```

Comment: you right ! why didn't it come to my mind :( thats so simple thank you man